# Why does AngularJS 2 HTTP Post only accepts string data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, http-post

I am wondering why in AngularJS 2 (2.0.0-beta.13) the HTTP Post method only accepts string data as body and not a JavaScript object as is the case in AngularJS 1.

AngularJS-1:

```
$http.post(someUrl,someObject)
```

AngularJS-2:

```
http.post(someUrl, JSON.stringify(someObject))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because support for other types is not yet implemented https://github.com/angular/http/issues/75